# parsing the html with HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl, html-treebuilder

I want to parse the html page.Extract the badge , description , and the badge type using

```
      <div class="row">
       <div class="span8">
         <table id="badge-list">
           <tr>
             <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
             <td style="width: 200px;" class="badge-cell">
                <a class="badge-name" href="/badge/show/3/">
                    <span class="badge-icon bronze">&#8226;</span>
                     Editor
                </a>
                <span class="multiplier">x 3892</span></td>
              <td class="earned False">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>First edit</td>
           </tr>
```

my perl code is follows,

i am trying to extract  `a class="badge-name"` and other detail using the below code

```
      my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
      $tree->parse($content);
      my ($h1) = $tree->look_down('_tag', 'table', 'id', 'badge-list'); 
      my @tr = $h1->look_down('_tag', 'tr') ;

      foreach my  $tr (@tr) {
         my @tdList = $tr->look_down('_tag','td');

         foreach my $td ( @tdList) {
           if (my $a = $td->look_down('_tag','a')) {
               print $a->as_text , "\n";
               my $span = $a->look_down('_tag','span', 'class');
               print $span->attr('class');
           }
           else {
               my $text =  $td->as_text , "\n";    
               print "$text\n";
           }
      }

    }
```

This code is throwing warning `Wide character in print at ..`

Comment: To show the error would be useful here but perhaps instead of $a->look_down('_tag', 'span', 'class') use $a->look_down('_tag', 'span')->{class}

Comment: What does *“breaking”* mean?

Comment: `my $span = $a->look_down('_tag', 'span', sub { defined $_[0]->attr('class') });` will ensure the class must be defined.

Comment: @Borodin : I am seeing the above warning for ```print $a->as_text , "\n";```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`look_down` requires *pairs* of attribute/value parameters.

```
$a->look_down('_tag','span', 'class')
```

should be just

```
$a->look_down('_tag','span')
```

Comment: Does `HTML::TreeBuilder` support **timeout** to limit `HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url)` in any fashion beside using `eval`-`alarm` duet?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add "use utf8;" at the start of the script to add support non ASCII symbols in the print. The symbol • is deferentially is wide.

```
use utf8;
```